# What to fill this with?

Tags: landscaping

trying to figure how how to best fill this ditch/hole. I read about leveling with a mix of compost, sand, and top soil, but that was for smaller holes. For larger holes I read maybe just doing top soil. Would appreciate any thoughts or recommendations.

[image]

Comment: If the "ditch or swale" is serving to move rainwater away, filling it may cause issues with flooding and a muddy mess where the fill becomes saturated as the unerlying ground countrours continue to direct water to the same area, but now it's full of fill-dirt that turns to soup.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to what looks like a circular depression near the shed and garden patch.

Compost will partially decay over time and leave a depression, but shallower than what you have.

Topsoil is your best bet, but ensure that you keep any slope away from structures.

You will also want to fill it a bit higher (couple of inches) than the surrounding soil as the new soil will compact over time.

Comment: That is exactly right, thanks!!